# Powershell Keeps Resetting To Default Temp Folder

Tags: sql-server, powershell, temp

I am running a PowerShell script that extracts data from a database. However, I do not have enough space on the default `%Appdata%Local/Temp/` folder. I know this because I get the error:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect
>   key file for table
>   'C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp#sql7ec_3_3.MYI'; try
>   to repair it"

To fix this issue I am trying to change the Temp folder for PowerShell. I have changed it in regedit to:

```
TMP   D:\Temp
Temp  D:\Temp
```

In addition I run this code at the start of my script:

```
# Set Environmental Variables
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", "D:\Temp\")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Temp", "D:\Temp\")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", "D:\Temp\")

# Navigate to these temp folders
$TempDir = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
cd $TempDir # This actually returns 'D:\Temp\'
```

However, when the script runs I still get the error message:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect
>   key file for table
>   'C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp#sql7ec_3_3.MYI'; try
>   to repair it"

Any advice on why it is defaulting to the %Appdata% folder and how to change it?

Comment: Can you include justification of your conclusion that lack of disk space is the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are running the script on the machine where the database resides or remotely? Could the error message relate to the state of a remote machine?

Comment: Can you check the path in your first paragraph. Not sure that you mean to have percent signs around "AppData" as that isn't what it is the error message and `%AppData%` usually points at the "Roaming" folder.

Comment: Where is your code?  Your question doesn't actually state anything that others could help with.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt if you research the error it comes up with two possibilities. 1. Low disk space, 2. Corrupted Table. In this case it was the former. 

The DB was run locally, but it still had the issue of being ran in a separate program. See the answer I posted.

As for the path, I just posted that to as quick overview, if you look at the error message it does five the full path.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The rest of the code was irrelevant. The issue was that the database had a different TEMP folder than powershell

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and it was to do with the Environmental Variables. I correctly changed the TEMP environment for PowerShell, however, since I called a DB it was the DB doing the actual calculation and using its own TEMP folder separate from PowerShell. When I changed the TEMP file location for the MySQL database it worked perfectly.